# Using "withTaskGroup" and "async let" together

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, parallel-processing

Following is a simplified version of how I'm using `withTaskGroup`:

```swift
let allResults = await withTaskGroup(of: ([Double], Float, Float, Int).self,
                                     returning: FinalResult.self,
                                     body: { taskGroup in

    for operation in operations {
        taskGroup.addTask { @MainActor in
            let value = await operation.execute()
            return value
        }
    }
    
    // Collect child task results here...
})
```

The `execute` function looks as follows where the processes include fairly math calculation intensive tasks such as feature extractions for a machine learning model:

```swift
func execute() async -> ([Double], Float, Float, Int) {
    async let result0: [Double] = process0() ?? []
    async let result1: Float = process1() ?? -1
    async let result2: Float = process2()
    async let result3: Int = process3()
    return (await result0, await result1, await result2, await result3)
}
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that the final result is inconsistent where sometimes I get proper results and sometimes not.  An example would be that sometimes I get an array of all zeros for 512 features (array length) when they're supposed to be non zero numbers. Contrarily, if I were to simply use a `for loop` instead of `withTaskGroup`, the result seems to be a bit more consistent.

So I'm wondering if there are any consequences of using `withTaskGroup` and `async let` together since this is a parallel of a parallel.  Unlike concurrency, my understanding of parallelism is that each core of CPU is assigned to process the tasks simultaneously, but if I were to provide 4 `operations`, that means 4 x 4 = 16 parallel processes, which is more than the number of available cores.

Comment: There should be no problem with `async let` in conjunction with task groups. Your problem likely rests elsewhere. I would suggest creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem.

Comment: In swift Concurrency parallel or not can not be determined by that way. It is decided by the Actor's executor and task required Context. And if you want to design high-performance parallelism execution. You should use `libDispatch`'s `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations:execute:)` with dedicate synchronization. In fact, swift Concurrency is not designed to aim the parallel execution. `TaskGroup` is pretty slow for large parallel execution.

Comment: @Watermelon can I use `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations:execute:)` alongside async-await?

Comment: FWIW, if you have data races, as Rob Napier hypothesizes, shifting to `concurrentPerform` will do nothing to fix that. And in well-engineered parallel code (where you “stride” to maximize the work per iteration) the difference between `concurrentPerform` and task group becomes largely inconsequential. Besides, bigger picture, if you’re doing a lot of CoreML, the benefits of parallelism in the CPU is somewhat diminished when the calculations are GPU or NN bound.

Comment: In answer to your question, you technically can use `concurrentPerform` in conjunction with `async`-`await`. But it’s not ideal, because the cooperative thread pool can no longer reason about CPU usage if you have GCD tying up the cores. If you’re not really pushing the cooperative thread pool while you are using `concurrentPerform`, though, this is likely minimal concern. But like I said, my empirical comparisons between well-engineered `concurrentPerform` and task groups shows very modest benefits, anyway. Besides, you should probably fix your data race (or whatever) issues first.

Comment: @Rob Thank you very much. This is very informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not the problem. The problem is much more likely that your code in `process1()`, etc., is not thread-safe (relying on data read from properties that aren't thread-safe, for example, or manipulating the returned Array in an invalid way). Exceeding the number of cores is not going to cause a logic problem if you've otherwise written the code correctly. It can cause performance problems, depending on many factors, but it will not cause problems with correctness.

You may want to turn on "Strict Concurrency Checking" in your build settings, which can help you find mistakes. (It can also find a lot of issues in Foundation which you can't fix, so it's sometimes best to use it on isolated code or a smaller project.)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try the Strict Concurrency checking setting.  Could this alway be related to data race?

Comment: No, there are several possible bugs. It depends on what is in the `process` code. But given your description, the first thing I'd assume is that you're accessing data across threads in an invalid way.